# File exists in windows drive

Tags: workflow, picture

I've created a sharepoint workflow which attach the picture from C: drive (of email recipient) and show in outlook email. However, some of the users are on windows 7 and some of them are on windows 10, which cause change of the file path. So, I would like to know if there is any code to detect the windows version or if file exists in the c drive of email recipient?

Sharepoint version is O365

Thanks

Comment: if anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If path describes a directory, this method returns false. See [how to fix confirm form resubmission](https://www.stuffroots.com/fix-confirm-form-resubmission/) and Trailing spaces are removed from the path parameter before determining if the file exists. The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists.

Comment: I think you're missing something.  This answer seems incomplete.